# Modifying data in PostgreSQL using javascript AJAX single quote error

Tags: javascript, ajax, postgresql

Modifying data in PostgreSQL in javascript where URL contains a single quote

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

In some of these approaches, success is printing but there are no changes to the database.

Attempts

```
first_name = D'Angelo
first_name = D%27Angelo
first_name = D\'Angelo
first_name = 'D''Angelo'
first_name = D\\\'Angelo
```

database

```
 _______________________________
|first_name|last_name|is_present|
---------------------------------
| D'Angelo |Williams |  false   |
---------------------------------
| Georgia  | Fritz   |  false   |
---------------------------------
|   Luca   | O'Keefe |  false   |
 _______________________________
```

file.js

```
modify_student_data = "D'Angelo: Williams :false"
first_name = "D'Angelo";
last_name = "Williams";
is_present = "true";
$.ajax({ url:'/data/student_attendance/' + modify_student_data + "*" + first_name + ':' + last_name + ':'+ is_present,
    success: function (result){
       console.log("Success");
    }
    error: function (er){
       console.log("error");
    }
});
```

desired outcome

```
 _______________________________
|first_name|last_name|is_present|
---------------------------------
| D'Angelo |Williams |   true   |
---------------------------------
| Georgia  | Fritz   |  false   |
---------------------------------
|   Luca   | O'Keefe |  false   |
 _______________________________
```